# STM32 SPI Interrupt & DMA not working, polling is

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt

I'm using STM32H7A3 nucleo, manage to get SPI polling working, enclose code below, when I try in implement Interrupt and DMA , the code compile successfully with no error, but SPI outputs no signal. SPI slave device is a TI ADC. I have set SPI global interrupt and DMA circular.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef spi_write(reg, *pData)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;
  uint8_t sendData[2] = {reg, *pData};
 
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(...);  // CS pull low
  ret = HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi1, sendData, 2, 20);
// ret = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, sendData, 2, 20);
  if  (ret != HAL_OK)
  {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(..);  // CS high
  }
```

The code is working for polling. TI ADC is able to read and sent data, but not interrupt and DMA mode.

Hello, anyone can kindly advise...thx

Comment: I think the last line is incomplete...

Comment: yes need to pull high, i hav this in the polling and its working, but not interrupt & DMA...

Comment: You didn't present DMA configuration, and the problem is either that you didn't activate DMA in the SPI peripheral, or DMA is misconfigured.

Comment: DMA is activated here ret = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, sendData, 2, 20); inside the spi_write function...

Comment: No, it's a call to DMA transmit function. But before you do that, DMA needs to be configured (usually only once upon power up) to work with the specific peripheral.

Comment: hi, could kindly advise with a simple code on SPI with DMA i am a final-year student working on STM32 for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are not blocking, only set up the transition and return immediately.

It means that they do not wait until the transition is completed.

Then you pull the CS up before the transition ends. You need to do it in the interrupt callbacks/

Comment: Thx could you help to write a short brief code to further elaborate? not quite understand your answer

Comment: yes u are right they are interrupt and DMA cos i have already get the polling working...